# Sorting a collection in backbone numerically

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js

So I'm sorting items like this:

```
sorted_items = new Backbone.Collection items.sortBy((item) ->
  return item.get("position")
)
```

where items is already a collection. But I want sorted_items to be sorted by the field position which can be numbers from 1-1000. I know backbone sorts it alphabetically so right now its sorting it like: 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20... etc

Rather than 1, 2, 3, 4... etc

Now is there an easy way to do this or do I have to stick zeros before every position?

Comment: What if you change that to `return +item.get("position");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like position is returning a string. You can either change your data source to make position an integer or use parseInt in your sort function:

```
return parseInt(item.get("position"), 10)
```

Comment: What should be done if we have 2 numeric fields to be sorted ?